# How to get Audio EQ equalizer working with Streamus?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm talking about Chrome extensions [Audio EQ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-eq/lfafdlnjaliaghpjdajmlcnnblkgcefh?hl=en) and [Streamus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamus/jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd?hl=en). (And they're awesome.)

Is there a way to make Audio EQ affect the output of Streamus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you set the equaliser however you want it. Close chrome via task manager. Once this is done you can reopen chrome and all effects will have been applied. It is worth configuring the equaliser with YouTube as you can do that live, making the whole thing faster to do.